# Silverlight 4 Border Clipping

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, clipping

Is it possible in Silverlight 4 to create a border with rounded corners that clips any of it child UI Element?  So far I have attempted to do so by setting a button as a child element of a border control but the buttons does not get clipped when I set the corner radius to create rounded corners in the border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [ClippingBehavior](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61176#494852) that is part of the Expression Blend Samples on CodePlex. It's a Blend behavior, so to add it you have to reference System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from the Blend SDK and drop the behavior on the element in Blend or add it in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MainPage"
    ...other xmlns imports...
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:samples="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=Expression.Samples.Interactivity"
    >

    <Border>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <samples:ClippingBehavior CornerRadius="15"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <!-- content to be clipped goes here -->
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

This is a straightforward and reusable way to add rounded corners/clipping to any UI Element.

Comment: As is often the case with XAML snippets, the imports are missing, rendering what might be a great answer, not so great.

Comment: Updated with relevant xmlns imports and fixed the links to the ClippingBehavior source from the Expression Blend Samples project.

Comment: Are ypu sure you have placed the ...content... in the correct spot? I am getting a compiler error A value of type 'Border' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BehaviorCollection'. if am Im trying to place another border inside a clipping one.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, I believe you're right.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hi I keep getting `Error 1 A value of type 'ClippingBehavior' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BehaviorCollection'.`  What should I do?